# Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: open \path\to\jwt.hex: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: prysm

how can i solve this?

Error from Prism documentation in Step 3: Run an execution client

Answer (score 0):

The part of the docs you're looking at is [here](https://docs.prylabs.network/docs/install/install-with-script#step-3-run-an-execution-client), where it says to run the following command:

```
geth --http --http.api eth,net,engine,admin --authrpc.jwtsecret /path/to/jwt.hex
```

`/path/to/jwt.hex` is not supposed to be input precisely with that path - you're supposed to replace it with the path to the secret you generated using Prysm, mentioned above earlier in the docs. If you've been following the docs, it **might** be in `/home/YOUR_USERNAME/ethereum/consensus/prysm/jwt.hex`, assuming that you replace `YOUR_USERNAME` with your actual username. If you can't find it, if you're on a *nix system, you could run `find / -name "jwt.hex"`, but that might take a while, depending on your specs and how much stuff is on your machine. (Apparently you have to use a [different command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37641118) on Windows.)